# Not able to get data after mapping array of objects in to list-reactjs

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, redux

Sample JSON

```
 "data": {
    "title": "test2",
    "selectedBoardData": {
        "boardId": "1070",
        "boardTitle": "My New Board",
        "createdAt": 1526385544606,
        "modifiedAt": 1526390958854,
        "spcxId": "1070",
        "widgetList": [
            {
                "widgetId": "3b728bae-1c5a-4f48-a0c7-f9c8f0b13199",
                "widgetName": "widget 0",
                "widgetType": "venn",
                "leftTarget": "MALE",
                "rightTarget": "HHMALE",
                "leftTargetValue": 117112,
                "rightTargetValue": 160432,
                "position": {
                    "row": 0,
                    "col": 0
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Trying to iterate

getting data  for action.payload.selectedBoardData.widgetList.map
but later i am not able to get data.

please let me if there is any error.

Not able find out what is wrong in this.

code

```
  const storyboardlist = action.payload.selectedBoardData.widgetList.map(widgetDataList => ({
    leftTarget: widgetDataList.leftTarget,
    rightTarget: widgetDataList.rightTarget,
    leftTargetValue: widgetDataList.leftTargetValue,
    rightTargetValue: widgetDataList.rightTargetValue,
    position: widgetDataList.position,
    //})),
  }));
  return { ...state, boardList: storyboardlist };
```

Comment: Sample object first key is `data` not `selectedBoardData`

Comment: @lomboboo you mean i need to add 'data' also

Comment: yes, action.payload is your sample object that starts with `data` key

Comment: @lomboboo still i am not able to get

Comment: Just debug what do you get from `action.payload` and paste console.log here

Comment: @JMR what do you mean by `not able to get data` ?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN yes i not able to get data after iterating

Comment: :
boardId
:
"361c55a9-e85a-4b95-b1d2-b9912acad3b5"
boardTitle
:
"Board59"
createdAt
:
1527679112203
modifiedAt
:
1527679151553
spcxId
:
""
widgetList
:
Array(1)
0
:
{widgetId: "ee23235b-4034-4443-98fc-47b783610311", widgetName: "widget 0", widgetType: "venn", leftTarget: "MALE", rightTarget: "PSHGMALE", …}

Comment: @lomboboo pasted console of action.payload

Comment: As the console log you posted it should be `action.payload.widgetList.map`

Comment: What if you `console.log(action.payload.data)` what it is the output? or `console.log(action.payload.selectedBoardData.widgetList)`

Comment: console.log(action.payload.data)===undefined

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(action.payload.selectedBoardData)` ?

Comment: i have pasted in the above comment

Comment: @JMR firstly, paste output into the question with right formatting, secondly your Sample data is obviously different from what you posted as output. Problem is not with the `map` but rather with your understanding of what you get from server (or somewhere else)

Answer (score 1):

Your `.map()` code is fine.

It's just the way you are getting the array, try to console.log() these references to find out: `action.payload.widgetList`, `action.payload.selectedBoardData.widgetList`